# A bullet point is appearing beside my wordpress custom sidebar

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I created a custom wordpress theme and sidebar for it, when I place the sidebar where I want it to be a bullet point appears beside the sidebar itself (outside not text inside) how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Another option being you could put
    .widget {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
in your css/sass/less file if you wanted it not to appear on any!

Answer (score 0):

The default sidebar args are:

```
$args = array(
    'name'          => sprintf( __( 'Sidebar %d' ), $i ),
    'id'            => "sidebar-$i",
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => "</li>\n",
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => "</h2>\n",
);
```

Which wraps all of your widgets in `li`. You'll need to change these args in your sidebar registration. Specifically the `before_widget` and `after_widget`.

```
$args = array(
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>\n",
);

register_sidebar($args);
```

Alternatively, you could adjust the styles in your theme to hide the bullets.